# Where can I find the Hindu scriptures in Sanskrit with Hindi rendition/translation?

Tags: scripture, translation-request

I want to get the online source or reference from where I can find the Hindu Scriptures with Sanskrit verse and Hindi rendition/translation. So, give me the list or website or online source/references which have collection of authentic Hindu scriptures.

Comment: type vedapuran in google u will find many download links

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Can you help me in finding the [Mukatika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muktika_Upanishad) [Upanishad](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/muktika.html?lang=sa) with Hindi translation?

Comment: Visitors are requested to contribute by posting answer if they know about helpful sources

Comment: @Pandya there is english translation to Muktikaa Upnishat available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am Listing here some of the sources I've used.

- Digital Library of India. Links: [1](http://dli.gov.in/), [2](http://dli.ernet.in/), [3](http://dli.serc.iisc.ernet.in/).
- [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/)
- [Sanskrit Documents](http://sanskritdocuments.org/) for Sanskrit verses

Comment: You can find many scriptures on Ved Purana in Hindi. http://vedpuran.net/download-all-ved-and-puran-pdf-hindi-free/

Comment: Add [Indian Scriptures](http://www.indianscriptures.com/).