# What are some online sources to get unabridged Hindu Scriptures or to learn Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, resource

What are some good websites to find unabridged versions of Hindu Scriptures and to learn Hinduism (with proper interpretations)?

Also, see:

- [Where can I find/get basic information about Hinduism on the web?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10599/3500)
- [Where can I find the Hindu scriptures in Sanskrit with Hindi rendition/translation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9532/3500)
- [Complete English translations of Puranas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9078/3500)
- [I want to learn Sanskrit. Can anybody guide me how to start?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9676/3500)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Here are some sources.

1. [Hindu scriptures](http://www.indianscriptures.com) - Best site to get Hindu Scriptures in Sanskrit and English. This site has all main scriptures such as Vedas, Upanishads and Puranas and many other Ancient Scientific literature. (This site is getting revamped now with new design.  Click on [hinduscriptures.in](http://hinduscriptures.in/) to read introduction to Hindu scriptures
2. [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/index.php) - This is another best site to get scriptures for free. [Sanskrit ebooks](http://www.sanskritebooks.org) and [Hinduism ebooks](https://hinduebooks.blogspot.in) have index of useful books uploaded to Archive.org.
3. [Sacred Texts Hinduism](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/) - This site has good collection of scriptures such as four Vedas (separately in both Sanskrit and English), Mahabharata, some Puranas. Most of the works were translated by Foreign authors.
4. [Sanskrit Documents](http://sanskritdocuments.org/) - This site has an excellent collection of various scriptures (original Sanskrit verses) and many useful sites to get Hindu Scriptures, also Sanskrit Learning resources and processing tools. Some notable useful resources linked are:

- List of digital repository of [Scanned Books](http://sanskritdocuments.org/scannedbooks/)
- Sanskrit e-texts, literature, scriptures, and stotras [available elsewhere](https://sanskritdocuments.org/TextsElsewhere/) and links to [Scriptures and Stotras](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_links/links3_scriptures.php)
- [Related sites](http://sanskritdocuments.org/sites/) and [Book Stores](https://sanskritdocuments.org/books/).

8. [Bhagavadgita.us](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/) - This site has Bhagavad Gita with commentaries from eminent Acharyas such as Adishankaracharya, Ramanujacharya, Madhva and Gaudiya Philosophers. (Only site of Bhagavadgita with multiple commentaries).
9. [Holybooks Hinduism](http://www.holybooks.com/category/hinduism/) - For all kind of Hindu Scriptures in short size including works of modern Yogis.
10. [Sankaracharya.org](http://sankaracharya.org/) - Best site for various topics such as Advaita Basics, Advaita Discussions, English translation of some works of Adi Shankaracharya, Upanishads, Bhagavad Gita, Brahma Sutras.
11. [Veda base](https://www.vedabase.com/) - Best site for Srimad Bhagavatam and Gaudiya Vaishnava literature.
12. [Vedanta Shastras Library](http://www.shastras.com/) - Great site to learn Vedas, Upanishads, Brahmasutras. - For English translation of Vedanta Prashthanatrayi, Vedas, Epics, Purans, Literature of Adi Shankara, Ramkrishna and Krishnamurti and some stotras, mantras and rituals, stories etc.
13. [Tirumala ebooks](http://ebooks.tirumala.org/) - For books on Tirumala Temple, Visistadvaita Philosophy, Regional books (especially Telugu, Tamil and Hindi).
14. [Valmikiramayana.net](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/) and [Valmiki Ramayana from IITK](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/) - Former one has unabridged Ramayana without uttara Kahnda while latter one has Verses of Ramayana in major Indian Languages.
15. [Mahabharatha Resources](http://mahabharata-resources.org/) - For complete Mahabhartha including Hari Vamsa Parva.
16. [Shaivam.org](http://shaivam.org/) - For scriptures of Lord Shiva and Shaivism.
17. [Himalayanacademy.com](https://www.himalayanacademy.com/) - For Scriptures related to [Agamas](https://www.himalayanacademy.com/site/search/tags/Agama), Hindu Scriptures, Shiva-centric texts and other Spiritual books
18. [Vedic reserve of Maharshi University](http://vedicreserve.mum.edu/) and [GRETIL](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil.html) - Former one has all Hindu Scriptures in Sanskrit (Devanagari) while latter one has Scriptures in IAST (Unicode (UTF-8)).
19. [Wisdom Library Hinduism](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism) - For Patanjali Yogasutras, Manusmriti, Brahma Sutras and some Upanishads.
20. [WestBengal Dspace](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in/) - For Puranas in English language and Bengali.
21. [advaita-vedanta.org](http://www.advaita-vedanta.org/) - For books and information about Advaita Vedanta including complete works of Sri Adishankaracharya.
22. [Astrojyoti.com](http://www.astrojyoti.com/) - For various Gitas, tantras, Jyotishya books and abridged versions of puranas.
23. [Aghori.it](http://www.aghori.it/aghori_eng.htm) - This site has information about Tantra, Sri Chakra, Chakras and other Gitas.
24. [thevaaram.org](http://thevaaram.org/index.php) - Complete [Tirumurai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tirumurai) of 12 Volumes with original verses and translation into various languages by [Dharmapuram Adheenam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharmapuram_Adheenam).
25. [Belur Math](http://ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/complete_works.htm) - Complete works of Sri Swami Vivekananda.
26. [Telugu Bhakthi](http://www.telugubhakti.com/telugupages/main.htm) - For scriptures in Telugu language.
27. [Hinduonline.co](http://hinduonline.co/Books/BooksOnline.html) - For scriptures in Sanskrit
28. [Vedarahasya.net](http://vedarahasya.net/) - This site contains a few articles of Sri Maha Perival, translations of prime vedic scriptures, some rare photographs and few interesting links to other sites in the Internet
29. [Kamakoti.org](http://www.kamakoti.org/) - This site has works of Sri Adishankaracharya, history of Kanchi Peetam, essence of Puranas and many other books on Sanatana Dharma. This site also provides Scriptures and other books in Telugu and Tamil.

    - [Works](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/Adi%20Sankara%20Focus.html) of Adi Shankaracharya
    - [Essence](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/puranashome.html) of Puaranas
    - [Unabridged Puranas](http://www.kamakoti.org/telugu/) in Sanskrit and Telugu (Telugu Script).
30. [Digital Library of India](http://www.dli.ernet.in/)
31. [Digital Corpus of Sanskrit](http://kjc-sv013.kjc.uni-heidelberg.de/dcs/): Only Sanskrit scriptures.
32. [Ancient Voice](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/)
33. [Gita press IITK](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/): Various translations and commentaries on [Srimad Bhagavad Gita](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=1&field_nsutra_value=1). Other Gitas, Brahma Sutra, Yog Sutra, Valmiki Ramayana, Ramacharitmanas and Principle Upanishads available in Sanskrit and in some Indian languages.
34. [Puranic Encyclopedia](http://nitaaiveda.com/All_Scriptures_By_Acharyas/Puranas/Puranic_Encyclopedia.htm) (nitaaiveda.com) or [Puranic Encyclopedia](https://archive.org/details/puranicencyclopa00maniuoft) (archive.org)
35. [sanskritweb.net](http://www.sanskritweb.net/) - For Vedas and few other scriptures in Devanagari (Text searchable formats).
36. [Vedpuran.net](https://vedpuran.net/) - For scriptures in Hindi and other languages. It contains mainly abridged versions.
37. [literature.awgp.org](http://literature.awgp.org/) - (From Gayatri Parivar) For books, magazines and articles related to various Hinduism topics. Also various Shruti and Smriti treatise in Hindi.
38. [acharya.org](http://acharya.org/bk/pb/index.html) - Sri Vaishnava books.
39. [Holy Teachings of Vedanta](http://estudantedavedanta.net/veliingles.html) - [pdf] Vedanta text e.g. Bhagavad Gita, Upanishads, Brahma Sutras etc. all with various commentaries and English translation. Ramayana, Yoga Vashishtha, Srimad Bhagavatam and many more books.
40. [Darshana Press](http://darshanapress.com/) - Word to word English translation of Shad Darshana (six school of Hindu philosophy) Sutras.

Some more additional Sites (sites of *Yogis* and *Acharyas*):

1. [Swamisivanda.org](http://sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?format=html), [dlshq.org](http://dlshq.org/download/download.htm) and [Swamikrishnanada.org](http://www.swami-krishnananda.org/index.html) - Best sites of Divine life society to learn various Yoga techniques and to get books on Spirituality and Philosophy.
2. [Sriramanamaharshi.org](http://www.sriramanamaharshi.org/) - For books and teaching of Sri Ramana Maharshi.
3. [Paramahamsa Yogananda](http://www.yogananda.com.au/) - For Kriya Yoga and Philosophy.
4. [sriaurobindoashram.org](https://www.sriaurobindoashram.org/sriaurobindo/writings.php) - For writings of Sri Aurobindo

**Note**: Please update this answer if you know any online sources that are out of copyright. Don't add another answer.

If you want to save this answer as PDF, visit [How do I get/print a particular Q/A in printer-friendly format?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/650/3500)

Comment: Direct link to print/save as PDF: [http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&service=hinduism.stackexchange&printer=false&question=15424](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&service=hinduism.stackexchange&printer=false&question=15424)

Comment: Where can I find the 108 Upanishads in English?