# Why Karna and Drona didn't use Brahmastra against Ghatotkacha?

Tags: mahabharata, karna, brahmastra, dronacharya, ghatotkacha

- Both Karna and Drona were capable of **using Brahmastra** while battling Ghatotkacha.
- Drona didn't use brahmastra and in the end Karna **used the Divine Weapon** that can be used only **One Time** against Ghatotkacha which was given by Lord Indra.

**QUESTION :**

- Why Both Drona and Karna didn't kill Ghatotkacha by using Brahmastra ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking in the last line. Your title question doesn't match with what you are asking in the body. BTW, are you doing some kind of research on Brahmāstra...why so many questions on Brahmāstra?!

Comment: @sv. i have edited it can you undertand that?

Comment: @sv. about Brahmastra it seems many places it caused different changes like it can take a crow's eye or it can cause complete destruction so only i referred the places that brahmastra were used and asked what was the reason for not using that as each as a reason

Comment: @UdayKrishna thanks  and  what about karna  not using brahmastra

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described in a number of [Purana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puranas), it was considered as a very destructive weapon. It is said that when the Brahmastra was discharged, there was neither a counterattack nor a defense that could stop it, except by **another Brahmastra**.

Karna didn't use *Brahmastra* against *Ghatotkacha* because he knew Arjun also had a *Brahmastra* to stop it. As Karna possessed a divine weapon **Vasavi Shakti**(-that *Lord Indra* had given to him), he saved that weapon for Arjun. But the Kaurava leader Duryodhana appealed to Karna to kill [Ghatotkacha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghatotkacha) And he was unable to refuse Duryodhana, Karna discharged that weapon against Ghatotkacha.

Comment: So are you saying Indra's Shakti was less powerful than a Brahmastra? Also, how can Arjuna stop a weapon of Karna fired on Ghatotkacha? I don't think war rules allowed that.

Comment: How karna can use brahmaasthra, is't he was cursed by parashurama?

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing,   as per Purans if two Bramhastra are used against each other.  They will cause destruction of everything i.e. Earth n Nature.

As when Lord Ram used Bramhastra against Ravana,  Ravan didn't used Bramhastra as he knw he had a boon from Brahma Dev,  which will protect him from brahmastra.  But if uses the Brahmastra against lord Ram Brahmastra then their wud b a complete annailation.

Likewise,  a warrior like Arjun too knws, what can happen if two Bramhastra used against each other.

Also Bramhastra was the divine weapon of the Creator (Brahma), having power destroy everything thing created by him.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism StackExchange! Visit [answer]. You should cite some sources.

Comment: @prit Friend this [Link](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15424/what-are-some-online-sources-to-get-unabridged-hindu-scriptures-or-to-learn-hind/15425#15425) has many sites that contain scriptures, that will be useful to you as you can search the puranas or Itihasa or hindu scriptures in these sites and copy the lines from it and paste in the answer