# Online Garuda purana

Tags: garuda-purana, book-recommendation

I am searching for an authentic source to read garuda purana in Hindi or english.
Share If there is any website or link.
Also any book recommendation will do the job.

Comment: Bookmark this answer for later use. [What are some online sources to get unabridged hindu scriptures](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15424/what-are-some-online-sources-to-get-unabridged-hindu-scriptures-or-to-learn-hind/15425#15425).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An English translation by Manmatha Nath Dutt is [available online here](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt) in proofread HTML. Also see a Sanskrit/English edition which is [available here](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/garud-puran/garuda-vol-1/chapter-01/topic-1) in PDF format.

If you are looking to buy the book, I can recommend two editions, one by Dutt, [edition 2012](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/garuda-purana-sanskrit-text-with-english-translation-set-of-2-volumes-NAL509/) and the other by various translators, [edition 2007](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/garuda-purana-3-volumes-IDE886/)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the book online in Sanskrit [here](http://www.astrojyoti.com/pdfs/DevanagariFiles/GarudaPurana.pdf).
The synopsis of the book in English is available [here](http://www.astrojyoti.com/garudapurana.htm). [This](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/gpu/index.htm) link has the English translation of the Purana.

Comment: Note that the link on sacred-texts.com is an abridged version of the Garuda Purana.