# Does god know our thoughts? and is it a sin to have lustful thoughts?

Tags: karma, sin

As far as I know,lusting is one of the biggest sin a person can commit.

Comment: no its not sin but gradually try to transform that lust into higher love ...

Comment: First you are asking if it is a sin? Then, you are answering your own question by saying it is? Are you open to the idea that its not a sin?

Comment: Per the Bhagavad gita 16.21 https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/16/21 lust, anger and greed are three gates leading to hell.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes God knows as he is antaryami or one who resides inside us.

The Vedas say that the Brahman or God has entered our body and has established himself in the mind.

> Shariram brahma prAvishat.
>
> ...........
>
> Brahman (or God) has entered our body.
>
> **AV 11.8.30**
>
> .................
>
> Eko ha devo manasi pravishtah.
>
> .............
>
> The sole God (or the one God) has established himself in the mind.
>
> **AV 10.8.28**

Also, even if we think that we are talking or thinking or doing something secretly there is always a divine witness who is observing everything. So, there is nothing which we can do or even think in mind which won't be noticed by God.

> Dvau samnishadya yat mantrayete rAja tat veda varunah tritiyah .
>
> ..................
>
> When you talk in secret, **there is always the third observer, divine
>   observer Varuna.**
>
> **AV 4.16.2**

```
As far as I know,lusting is one of the biggest sin a person can commit
```

No, that's wrong. Lust is innate in human and other beings as well. Its a natural pravritti that is born in humans everyday along with the other pravrittis like hunger, thirst, desire for sleep etc.

> Sarire JAyayate Nityam VAnchah NrinAm ChaturvidhAHa | Vubhuksha Cha
>   PipAsA SusupsA Cha RatisprihA ||
>
> ............
>
> Daily these four-fold desires are born in a human
>   body-hunger,thirst,desire for sleep and desire for sex (RatisprihA)
>
> **BhAvaprakash.**

So, being lusty in itself is not a sin. Just like being hungry or feeling sleepy are not sins.

But, if afflicted by lust one cohabits with someone who's another person's wife then that is a sin. If you are hungry then that's natural order but if tormented by hunger you eat something that's forbidden in scriptures then that becomes a sin.

**Abbreviations used :**

**AV 11.8.30 ------> Atharva Veda Samhita, KAnda 11, Sukta 8, Mantra 30 etc**.

Comment: a friend of mine is having a lustful thoughts about his mom.He feels bad.He tried his level best to control the thoughts but he end up entertaining them.I believe mothers are equal to god and lusting on them is a sin.Whenever he tries to control them,He will become anxious.is this a sin and what he can do to overcome this?

Comment: @AarVin Yes that is obviously a sin , a grave sin, he can try doing some yoga, pranayama to start with..

Comment: @Aar Vin Mother is not equal to God but instead she is far greater than God... Because our Shastra says.. 3 people matters a most in person's life and they are Guru, Pita and Mata. Guru is greater than God, and as per shastra Pita (father) is even Greater than Guru. Father considers as equal to 100 Gurus. And Mother is even greater than Father coz even 100 fathers can't match greatness of a Mother. So mother is far greater than Guru, father and God.

Comment: @Aar Vin The person who do sin toward his mother those person ended up by eating his own meat in Narka. They forcefully make them eat own body as a punishment. This punishment is for those who gives grief to their parents but what kind of sin you told, I can't even guess what will happen to him...

Comment: @Rishabh .......Because our Shastra says.. 3 people matters a most in person's life and they are Guru, Pita and Mata.......

Comment: @Rishabh Which  Shastra? Which verse line?

Comment: @AnuragSingh I don't read Shastra but instead I listen shastra from many resources like from someone's speech, television, satsang etc. But why you even want line no. for that. This is so basic info that I have shown here. All Hindu knows Guru is far greater than God for a person. That's why our shastra says "गुरुर्ब्रह्मा गुरुर्विष्णु र्गुरुर्देवो महेश्वरः गुरु साक्षात परब्रह्मा तस्मै श्रीगुरवे नमः". Means of this lines are "Guru is the Creator (Brahma), Guru is the Preserver(Vishnu), GuruDeva is Destroyer(Maheshwara) Guru is the absolute (singular) Lord himself, Salutations to that Sri Guru"

Comment: @AnuragSingh And Father and Mother are even greater than Guru. And Mother is the most greatest person in someone's life. That's why our shastra says.... "Mata ki seva se badi koi sewa nhi hoti, mata ke charno me hi swarg basaa hai". And also "Vidya daan iss sansar ka sabse badaa daan hai".

Comment: @AnuragSingh If you want reply with line no. then I can't give you line no. because I am not like other person in this site who just search on google and copy material from other sites and paste it here as an answer with line number. What info I use to give that info is based on my learning, in my wordings because I use my own words in my asnwer after reading or listening any info. I never copy others wordings but instead write my own, like in past Great saints use to do BUT now people only copy and paste, but am not like that.

Comment: @AnuragSingh First and last thing till now I copy and paste here only Guru's description in sanskrit and meaning of that info. Although I could have write Guru's greatness in my words also in brief but since you are so keen to know line no. and sanskrit words in reply that's why I did this for you so that you come to know that the info that I have given is not fake. See my answer and other answer on different post to know I use my own wordings instead of copy and paste from here and there.

Comment: @AnuragSingh I can also do google and find answer with line no. and sanskrit words BUT I never does that because this is not me.

Comment: @Rishabh I agree with you Rishabh. But our Shastras say- **Guru is greatest than anyone**.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Ok then I will try to find out true fact by posting it as question. Please be their and post your view as answer so that all can get to know it in brief. I also need to know about it in detail and I think comment section is not big enough to discuss this topic. So separate post will be best for it. Join me on there.

Answer (score 3):

> Does god knows our thoughts?

Offcourse God know our thoughts, that's why he called as Anteryami (who knows every feeling/thoughts/imagination of our). All of your imagination is use to store in brain as a memory and God can read brain because it's his creation.

> is it a sin to have lustful thoughts?

Thoughts alone can't do any sin but it's your decision (karma) that can do. What kind of decision you will make when your mind is full of lusting thoughts, that will decide sin or not.

To be more clear, decision (karma) can also be perform in non pysical way. For example: If someone is asking for help then if one will not do any help then this karma (decision, not phisical movement) is sin. That's mean you can do sin without moving phisicaly because some times not doing physical movement is sin. So your decision is know as karma, not your physical activities. And you will get Karma fal of your karma(decision).

**Points to remember**

In any case one must try to avoid these thoughts and should keep pure thoughts only. If you will keep negative feelings inside your mind than this feeling will force you to do any sin. Lets take an example of anger (another negative thought like lust), we all feel anger many times, and when our anger is more, then we lost control of our physical movement and eventually our movements started to act on its own and try to do anything that can calm our feelings of anger down. And we ended up doing any sin. We all have experienced result of our anger. So try to keep all negative thoughts away, so that these thoughts couldn't overtake control of our movements/decision.

**UPDATE**

I got this message below my answer

> Some of the information contained in this post requires additional references. Please edit to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or deleted.

In this message they told me to add references BUT I have learned those from Bhagwat geeta shown in Ramanand Sagar's Shree Krishna and Mahabharat on starplus. And I don't remember which episode was that.

If after reading this, you think tv shows (only my trusted tv shows, not all) is not reliable then even online info regarding this in text form on different sites are also don't have any reliability.

Comment: So when one decides to dwell on this lustful thoughts,the person is committing sin?

Comment: Didn't get your question. Please be more clear :)

Comment: I mean if a person decides to dwell on this lustful thoughts even when they know it's wrong,are they committing sin?

Comment: If those thoughts are towards someone's wife or own mother/sister then even thinking about this is surely a sin. You can think like that towards strangers but never about your own family or any married woman.

Comment: @rishabh,you are saying lust is sinful at the same time you are saying that it is okay to lust over another woman.No matter who the person we are lusting,we are still committing sin isn't?

Comment: @Rishabh - Sites like www.valmikiramayan.net/  , https://www.vedabase.com/ are fully trustworthy , they are viewed by millions and are close to accurate in translations. You can make use of them.You can also refere - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15424/what-are-some-online-sources-to-get-unabridged-hindu-scriptures-or-to-learn-hind

Comment: @Adhi These kinds of thoughts are in human nature. It is natural process and the responsible guy is Kaam Dev. Kaam Dev is the one one generate these kinds of thoughts in us. So it is not bad of having these thoughts. Because if we don't have these thoughts then why we would we marry someone. And since these thoughts is not sin but if these thoughts is being toward own sister then in that case it surely a sin. Is it that tuff to understand?

Comment: @rishabh,so having lustful thoughts are not bad but having lustful thoughts about own mother/sister is surely a sin?Am I correct?

Comment: @ Yes because these thoughts plays key role in continuity of life. Without this thought one will not even get marry with someone. No human can be born without these feeling. It is necessity that's why Lord created this feeling. Attraction towards opposite gender is rule of nature and extremely important. Although it is not sin, but still these thoughts will surely can drag someone to do any sin. Thats why its advisable to not let that thoughts heavy on mind.

Answer (score 2):

Annamayya, a great devotee of Lord Venkateswara states rhyming (in Telugu)   *Kaami gani vadu Mokshagami kaadu*. Among the four Purusharthas is contained lust, but must be confined to marriage relations only as a necessary transitional phase before attainment of Moksha.

EDIT1

Video [KonarakTempleOfEducaton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIpp4kratQ0) projects a view of ancient India (symbolically portrayed in temple architecture human interest education for every 5 years up to adulthood and beyond) when the four *Arthas* have their rightful and respected place in the Hindu scheme of life..start and end of lust included... reflecting Dr. Radhakrishna's quote that Hinduism is a way of life.

Answer (score 0):

God being the in-dweller obviously knows our thoughts. Nothing can ever be kept away from him.

Having sensuous thoughts is a sin as it provokes us to perform such deeds. But, yes kama is human nature. Fulfilment of sexual desire is a part of human life.

We must hence transcend the feelings of lust. Lust exists only so long as we see a difference between man and woman. If we see the cosmic being in all, there is no scope for lust. This is the best way to get rid off lustful feelings.

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE. We appreciate your active participation in answering questions on this Q?A  forum. But while answering questions on this site its' necessary to provide sources from authentic Hindu scriptures like Bhagavad Gita , Puranas , Upanishads etc. And this rule is mandatory. Pure personal opinions and wikipedia / blog sources generally are not encouraged in answers here .Please do provide some  sources in your answers from now on. Otherwise its possible that some of your answers will receive flags and will get deleted from  site. Also register on this site as a regular user .