# Do Gods know what we are thinking?

Tags: gods, vedanta, dharma, dharma-shastras, goddess

I am not just talking about our thoughts about them (deities), but just our thoughts in general, and the things that are in our minds (not talking about religion). I am asking this because deities are omnipresent.

Comment: Pick out any Stotram or respectable text amd you'll find equivalent words like sarvajña, sarvatra, sarva shaktimãna i.e., Omniscient, Omnipresent, Omnipotent, for almost all Major Gods. Thus, the Supreme knows everything, not only of the present, but also of the  past and future.

Comment: When you use the Western term "Gods" do you mean devas or Iswara? The use of unclear Western terms do not map one to one in Hinduism. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does god know our thoughts? and is it a sin to have lustful thoughts?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/does-god-know-our-thoughts-and-is-it-a-sin-to-have-lustful-thoughts)

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I meant "Devas" or "Devatas".

Comment: @Learning Hindu you can rectify the question to ask either about paramatma or devatas after seeing that devatas are not everywhere they’re in a lot of places but not everywhere. (See my comment below). If you ask about paramatma it’s duplicate. If you ask about devatas it may not be duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, nothing is hidden from the deities.

> O Arjuna! The **Lord dwells in the heart of all beings** revolving them
> all by His mysterious power Maya, as if they were objects mounted on a
> machine.

**Gita 18.61**

The Lord hidden in our hearts is called Antaryami and knows all our secrets including our thoughts.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the difference between "Devata" and "Ishwara"?

Comment: @LearningHindu Devatas are jivatmas of higher spirituality and having different tasks than us. Those who live in Div (Dyau) Loka are called devatas and **they’re NOT omnipresent**. Devatas include Indra, Varuna, Pushan (Adityas) Agni (Vasus) Viswedevas, etc. In charge of a particular function eg. Indra in charge of clouds thunder lightning, though lightning itself is Agni and rain itself is Varuna. Ishwara means someone like Bhagwan Vishnu, Mahadeva, Brahmaji, Tridevis. These are forms of the same paramatma who for creation destruction & preservation take various forms and this is omnipresent.

Comment: @LearningHindu, why don't you ask this as a question?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and this is because God is called paramAtmA, who dwells within every soul. gItA 15.15 says:

> sarvasya chAhaM hRRidi sanniviShTo mattaH smRRitir jnAnam apohanaM
>
> I am seated in everyone’s heart, and from Me come remembrance, knowledge and forgetfulness

ChAndogyopaniShad gives specific details about God and the desires of hearts. [1.7.6](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/chandogya-upanishad-english/d/doc238775.html):

> The person in the eye rules the world below him and also rules the desires of the human mind.

[1.6.8](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/chandogya-upanishad-english/d/doc238768.html):

> He also decides the wishes of the gods and goddesses.

There are a large number of references to God's knowledge of thoughts in the fourth book of the bhAgavata purANa.

4.9.19:

> vedAhaM te vyavasitaM hRRidi
>
> I know your desire in the heart

4.22.9:

> sarva-dRRishaM sarva AtmAnaM
>
> He is within everyone’s soul as the witness of everything

4.24.64:

> vidus taM puruShaM santam antar bhuNkte hRRiShIkair
>
> You know them and know how they are enjoying their senses.

4.30.29:

> kasmAn no veda nAshiShaH
>
> Why would you not know our desires?

6.4.42:

> chitta-jnaH sarva-bhUtAnAm
>
> who knows the minds of all