# Do god punish people who have intrusive thoughts?

Tags: gods

I have many intrusive thoughts in my daily life. Some include being very offensive to god himself. The thoughts that occur in my mind , I genuinely try to ask for forgiveness to god. So will god take offence in such matter? And are there any methods to reduce such thoughts in mind ? Thank you.

Comment: Related -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18454/4732