# Who is mother Durga, why was she prayed by all gods including Vishnu to be reborn as Parvathi?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, durga, parvati, sati-goddess

Mother Durga was reborn as Parvathi, the daughter of Mena and Himalaya. So why did the Gods including Vishnu pray to mother Durga to be reborn as Parvathi. Why were they happy of the marriage of Mena and Himalaya. 
Was Sati also a reincarnation of mother Durga ?

Comment: [This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19435/exact-relation-between-lord-shiva-and-goddess-kali/19440#19440) might help you l little to find out why :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you asked **Was Sati also a reincarnation of mother Durga ?**, you should also understand why Durga Devi was born as Sati Devi.

When Brahma created beings initially, they couldn't multiply or reproduce sexually. Lord Brahma wanted female energy or Shakti to make sexual reproduction possible (so that beings would be able to reproduce) and did Tapasya for Parameswara (Shiva with Shakti) and Lord Shiva appeared before him in Ardhanareswara form and gave female energy (shakti) needed for creation.

This is described in **[Chapter 3](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-ii/chapter-82/topic-1), Satarudra Samhita of Shiva Mahapurana**.

> यदा सृष्टाः प्रजाः सर्वा न व्यवर्द्धन्त वेधसा। 
>  तदा
> चिन्ताकुलोऽभूत्स तेन दुःखेन दुःखितः ॥ २॥
>
> When there had been little evolution of the people created by Brahma,
> he felt extremely painful.
>
> नभोवाणी तदाऽभूद्वै सृष्टिं मिथुनजां कुरु। 
>  तच्छ्रुत्वा मैथुनीं
> सृष्टिं ब्रह्मा कर्तुममन्यत॥ ३॥
>
> Then there was a divine sound from the sky said, "Carry on the
> creation produced by the couples' (i.e. the male and the female). Then
> Brahma thought of the creation based on the sexual relations.
>
> नारीणां कुलमीशानान्निर्गतं न पुरा यतः। 
>  ततो मैथुनजां सृष्टिं
> कर्तुं शेके न पद्मभूः॥४॥
>
> Earlier to that the race had not appeared out of the sexual
> intercourse with the females. Therefore Brahma could not create the
> world based on sexual relationship earlier.
>
> प्रभावेणा विना शम्भोर्न जायेरन्त्रिमाः प्रजाः। 
>  एवं
> सञ्चिन्तयन्ब्रह्मा तपः कर्तुं प्रचक्रमे॥ ५॥
>
> Brahma thought that the creation cannot be progressed without the
> influence of Šiva. Therefore he started performing tapas.
>
> शिवाय परया शक्त्या संयुक्त परमेश्वरम्।  
>  सञ्चिन्त्य हृदये प्रीत्या
> तपेशं परमं तपः।। ६॥
>
> Then he meditated upon Siva united with the great Sakti called
> Parameswara (Siva) in a combined way performing severe tapas.
>
> तीव्रेण तपसा तस्य संयुक्तस्य स्वयम्भुवः। 
>  अचिरेणैव कालेन तुतोष स
> शिवो द्रुतम्॥७॥
>
> Observing the severe austerities of Brahma, lord Siva was rapidly
> pleased with him within no time.
>
> ततः पूर्णचिदीशस्य मूर्तिमाविश्य कामदाम्। 
>  अर्द्धनारीनरो भूत्वा ततो
> ब्रह्मान्तिकं हरः॥८॥
>
> Then Isvara- the form of complete consciousness, entered into the
> Ardhanarisvara form, representing half male and half female and he
> appeared before Brahmā.

Brahma eulogized Him and Shiva gave His Shakti to Brahma.

> इत्युक्त्वा परमोदारं स्वभावमधुरं वचः। 
> पृथक्चकार वपुषो भागाद्देवीं
> शिवां शिवः॥ १३॥
>
> Thus Siva extremely large hearted, and Sweet tempered one, separated
> his body from that of Siva.
>
> तां दृष्ट्रा परमां शक्ति पृथग्भूतां शिवागताम्। 
>  प्रणिपत्य
> विनीतात्मा प्रार्थयामास तां विधिः॥ १४॥
>
> Looking at the Supreme Sakti, having been separated from the body of
> Siva, Brahma offered his salutation to her and then eulogised her.

Brahma then eulogized *Adi Shakthi*, the source of all *Shaktis* (female energy) in cosmos.  After Brahma's prayer, Shiva gave Her Shakti to Brahma and said She would born as daughter of Daksha Prajapati (as Sati Devi).

> शिव उवाच 
>  तपसाराधिता देवि! ब्रह्मणा परमेठिना। 
>  प्रसन्ना भव
> सुप्रीत्या कुरु तस्याखिलेप्सितम्॥ २६॥
>
> Siva said, “Brahma has adored you (Shakti or Sivaa) performing the tapas. Therefore
> getting pleased, you better fulfil his desires.”
>
> तामाज्ञां परमेशस्य शिरसा प्रतिगृह्य सा। 
>  ब्रह्मणो वचनाद्देवी
> दक्षस्य दुहिताऽभवत्॥ २७॥
>
> The goddess Paramesvari, accepting his command, according to the words
> of Brahma, she became the daughter of Daksa Prajapati.
>
> दत्त्वैवमतुलां शक्तिं ब्रह्मणे सा शिवा मुने!। 
>  विवेश देहं
> शम्भोर्हि शम्भुश्चान्तर्दधे प्रभुः॥ २८॥
>
> O Sage, then Sivaa (Shakti), giving the unique Śakti to Brahma, entered the body
> of Siva, who disappeared from the scene.
>
> तदाप्रभृति लोकेऽस्मिन्स्त्रिया भागः प्रकल्पितः। 
>  आनन्दं प्राप स
> विधिः सृष्टिर्जाता च मैथुनी॥ २९ ।।
>
> From that day onwards the share of the Woman, started to be given
> separately. Brahma then felt delighted and the creation based on
> sexual union started.

Lord Sada Shiva then took as Saguna form of *Rudra* (who dwells on Kailasa) and Durga or Adi Shakti (source of all Shaktis) born as Sati and Parvati in Saguna forms in different kalpas. The invisible form of Shakti (which mingled with Shiva) was born as Sati Devi first and then as Parvati and again will be born as Sati and this cycle repeats, which you can read in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14868/3500) in detail.

Brahma prayed to Durga to born as shakti in Saguna form for Rudra.

**[Chapter 10](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-i/chapter-32/topic-1) Rudra Samhita (Sati Khanda) of Shiva Mahapurana** says:

> Shiva said
>
> मद्रूपं परमं विष्णो ! ईदृशं ह्यङ्गतो विधेः। 
>  प्रकटीभविता लोके
> नाम्ना रुद्रः प्रकीर्तितः।।५४।। 
> "Visnu is my form. Similarly
> Rudra would be manifested from Brahma and shall be well known in the
> world by the same name. He will be my form.
>
> पूर्णरूपः स मे पूज्यः सदा वां सर्वकामकृत्। 
>  लयकर्ता गुणाध्यक्षो
> निर्विशेषः सुयोगकृत्।॥५५॥
>
> He is my complete form and lord of all the gunas and is worthy of
> being Worshipped by you. He will fulfil all your desires.
>
> त्रिदेवा अपि मे रूपं हरः पूर्णो विशेषतः। 
>  उमाया अपि रूपाणि
> भविष्यन्ति त्रिधा सुतौ।५६।
>
> Brahmā, Visnu and Siva are my forms. Hara is especially my complete
> form. Similarly Uma shall also have three forms.
>
> लक्ष्मीनर्गम हरे: पत्री ब्रह्मपत्री सरस्वती। 
>  पूर्णरूपा सती नाम
> रुद्रपत्नी भविष्यति।॥५७॥
>
> As Laksmi, she would be the spouse of Visnu, as Sarasvati, the spouse
> of Brahma, and as Rudra Patni (as Sati)- having the complete form,
> would be the spouse of Rudra.”

Daksha, at command of Brahma, prayed to Durga and got Her as daughter. **[Chapter 11](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-i/chapter-33/topic-1) Rudra Samhita (Sati Khanda)** says:

> यदुक्तं भवथा ब्रह्मन्! समस्तं सत्यमेव तत्। 
>  मदृते मोहयित्रीह
> शङ्करस्य न विद्यते।।४२।।
>
> Durga said, "O Brahma, whatever has been spoken by you, is utterly
> true. There is none else in the world to captivate Siva.
>
> हरेऽगृहीतदारे तु सृष्टिर्नैषा सनातनी। 
>  भविष्यतीति तत्सत्यं भवता
> प्रतिपादितम्।।४३।।
>
> You have spoken a great truth that if Siva does not take a wife unto
> Himself, the creation cannot continue long.
>
> ममापि मोहने यन्नो विद्यतेऽस्य महाप्रभोः। 
>  त्वद्वाक्याद्द्वगुणो
> मेऽद्य प्रयत्नोऽभूत्स निर्भरः॥४४॥
>
> I had also not been able to captivate the great lord, but at your
> Words my mind has been filled with double the enthusiasm.
>
> अहं तथा यतिष्यामि यथा दारपरिग्रहम्।। 
>  हरः करिष्यति विधे ! स्वयमेव
> विमोहितः॥४५ ।।
>
> O Brahma, I shall do something by which - Siva getting captivated
> would himself accept a spouse.
>
> सतीमूर्तिमहं धृत्वा तस्यैव वशवर्तिनी। 
>  महाभागा
> लक्ष्मीर्विष्णोर्यथाप्रिया।।४६।।
>
> As Laksmi is the beloved of Visnu, similarly, I taking to the form of
> Sati shall obey the command of Siva.

After Marriage, Daksha didn't invite Shiva to Yajna and Sati immolated Herself and mingled with Adi Shakti or Durga .

Now all other Gods with Vishnu again wanted to make Durga Devi born in Saguna form for Rudra who was left without wife and became detached from wordly activities.

**[Chapter 3](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-i/chapter-98/topic-1), Rudra Samhita (Parvati Khanda) says:**

> ब्रहोवाच
>
> इति श्रुत्वा महीधरस्य वचनं ते सुरास्तदा। 
>  ऊचुर्हर्यादयः प्रीताः
> सिद्धि मत्वा स्वकार्यतः।।१७।।
>
> Brahma said, "Listening to the words of Himacala, Visnu and other
> gods, felt delighted, expecting the Success of their mission and they
> spoke.
>
> देवा ऊचुः 
>  हिमाचल! महाप्राज्ञ! शृण्वस्मद्वचनं हितम्। 
> यदर्थमागताः सर्वे तद्ब्रूमः प्रीतितो वयम्।।१८।।
>
> The gods said, “O immensely wise Himacala, listen to our benevolent
> words. We shall now reveal the purpose for which we have arrived here.
>
> या पुरा जगदम्बोमा दक्षकन्याऽभवद्रगिरे!। 
>  रुद्रपत्री हि सा भूत्वा
> चिक्रीड सुचिरं भुवि।१९।।
>
> Sati, the daughter of Daksa and the wife of Siva in earlier times, had
> been enjoying sports on earth in the form of Uma.
>
> पितृतोऽनादरं प्राप्य संस्मृत्य स्वपणं सती। 
>  जगाम स्वपदं त्यक्त्वा
> तच्छरीरं तदाम्बिका।२०।
>
> Having been insulted by her father, remembering her pledge, getting
> rid of her human body, she achieved the supreme position.
>
> सा कथा विदिता लोके तवापि हिमभूधरः। एवं सति महालाभो भवेद्देवगणस्य
> हि।२१।। 
> सर्वस्य भवतश्चापि स्युः सर्वे ते वशाः सुराः।।२२।।
>
> The relevant story, O Himacala is well known to you. The gods too will
> be under your control.”
>
> ब्रहोवाच  
>  इत्याकण्र्य वचस्तेषां हर्यादीनां गिरीश्वरः।  
> तथास्त्विति प्रसन्नात्मा प्रोवाच न च अादरात्।।२३।।
>
> Brahma said, "On hearing the words of Visnu and other gods, the
> delighted lord Himacala said, "Be it so.' Then he adored them with
> respect.

Thereafter Gods paryed to Durga Devi and Durga Devi agreed to born as daughter to couple of Menaka and Himachala.

**[Chapter 4](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-i/chapter-99/topic-1) Rudra Samhita (Parvati  Khanda)** says

> उमोवाच हे हरे! विधे! देवा! मुनयश्च गतव्यथा:।  
>  सर्वे शृणुत
> मद्वाक्यं प्रसन्नाऽहं न संशयः।।२३।।
>
> Uma said, "O Visnu, O Brahma, O other gods, let all of you be
> comfortable. Listen to my words. I am undoubtedly pleased with all of
> you.
>
> चरितं मम सर्वत्र त्रैलोक्यस्य सुखावहम्॥  
>  कृतं मयैव सकलं
> दक्षमोहादिकं च तत्।।२४।।
>
> My performance always provides comforts to all the three worlds. The
> sport relating to the yajna of Daksa, was performed by me.
>
> अवतारं करिष्यामि क्षितौ पूर्णं न संशयः।   
>  बहवो हेतवोऽप्यत्र
> तद्वदामि महादरात्।।२५।।
>
> I shall surely appear on earth, with full incarnation. There are
> several reasons for the same, which I am going to highlight with
> respect.
>
> पुरा हिमाचलो देवा मेना चातिसुभक्तितः। सेवां मे चक्रतुस्तात!
> जननीवत्सतीतनोः।।२६।।
>
> O Gods, earlier when I was born as Sati, then both Himalaya and Mena
> had served me lovingly as parents.
>
> इदानीं कुरुतः सेवां सुभक्त्या मम नित्यशः।  
>  मेना विशेषतस्तत्र
> सुतात्वे नात्र संशयः।।२७।।
>
> Even presently both of them are serving me with utmost devotion. Out
> of both of them, Menaka, serves me particularly as a daughter.

Later Tarakasura performed Tapasya and got a boon from Brahma that only son born from Seed of Shiva  can kill him. This made Gods to speed up their marriage related works.

Comment: I think there is a confusion sati was not born from Himalaya and Meena like you said.

Comment: @Iku Parvati was born to Himalaya and Menaka not Sati.

Comment: @Iku Don't suggest edits overwriting what OP wrote.

Comment: What is OP?....

Comment: @Iku Original Poster.

Comment: Wrong is original? Why? Sati was not daughter of Himalaya and Mena...where did you get that, what is orignal poster how to get that? And what do you mean by severed (तोडऩा)? And after they got married then story of tarakasur starts.

Comment: @Iku Sati was daughter of Daksha and Parvati is daughter of Mena and Himalaya. Original Poster is the one who posts a "post", in this case "me". I rejected your edit because you wrote a line of "Kaama Deva and Rati" which i didn't make. You can read Rudra Samhita Parvati Khanda to know chronology of events.

Comment: [ok](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/padmapurana13.html) but still want to make a suggestion and ask one thing what do you mean exactly by the OP any links if any ques about OP is asked . ☺

Comment: @Iku It was Sati, not Parvati. Sati was served by that couple. Speaker is Durga or Adi Shakti.  So, Adi Shakti decided to take birth as their daughter in next incarnation as Parvati.

Comment: That's the problem, the couple you mentioned in your answer is himalya and mena with the name sati...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64818/discussion-between-the-destroyer-and-iku).

Comment: @Iku Don't assume that there is 1 Sati and 1 Parvati... There are [cycles of Sati and Parvati.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/wouldnt-most-of-the-incarnations-of-devi-be-of-sati-not-parvati/14868#14868)

Comment: Hmm that's not related... Name is name even if all God's are one you can't ever say something like you say names of  sarswti and Vishnu together.. You can't say Ganesha and kartikey are one

Comment: So you are saying that the Tridevs are avatars of Shiva but Rudra is more powerful and  Iikewise, the Tridevi are avatars of Aadi Shakti but Parvati is the most powerful, right?

Comment: @KVickneshvara Since it is Shiva purana, it appears to say the same. But if you analyze carefully, There's no hierarchy among Trimurtis and triDevis.

Comment: @The Destroyer What si meant by the fact that Shiva gave Shakti to Bramha? Does it mean that Shakti manifested as all the forms Bramha needed(aka Prakriti, Sarawati, Maya, etc) or did Shakti just talk to Bramha and instruct him on what to do or what?

Comment: Fabulous answer

Answer (score 2):

First sati came and after that she reborn as parvathi. Obviously world needed ma parvathi since if she is not there then shivji would not do anything in world and be a Sannyasi without Devi parvati [here](http://www.speakingtree.in/allslides/are-sati-and-parvati-the-same-person/m-lite) . from wiki 
**When Lord Shiva gave away his consort Adi-Shakti to the world for its welfare, Brahma ordered Daksha Prajapati to pray to mother Adi Parashakti-Durga for her to take birth as Daksha Prajapati`s Daughter. So the Goddess took human birth at the bidding of the god Brahma. Sati was born as a daughter of Daksha Prajapati and his wife Prasuti.**
All God's are prayed ..I have sort of confusion some says in starting there only one God shrihari Vishnu..some says Shiva..some says Adi parashakti...but one thing is clear whoever it is all the other gods prayed that God ...and why she was asked to reborn as parvathi ?? Ma durga herself said that in next janma she want to be born from  parents and father she could respect..so she was going to born anyways (this is in that link). But it's clear that the first time she born and the second time she born ..one reason is quite similar, that is Shiva need shakti in all aspects to do *sanchalan* of the world.

Comment: Pls.try to add sources in answers.  Here is the one for your above answer.-https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/7/59

Comment: @Iku the story you have linked doesn't answer why was Durga prayed and why was she asked to reborn as Paravathi.

Comment: Yes I got a link and I included it. And improved ans according to the @shivaneShambhuLinga 's comment ...thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

World not only need Tridev But also need Tridevis. Tridev is incomplete without Tridevis. And Shiva is incomplete without AAdi Shakti (Sati/Parvati).
System of world can't work properly until all Tridev won't perform their duties with Tridevis. Here is how..

> What's role of Tridevis with Tridevs?

Tridevs perform specific duties towards world and Tridevis helps Tridevs in their duties, Here is how..

- Brahma creates life and his wife (Sarsvati) gives knowledge to the
  life. Withought knowledge, life is meaningless. She is Goddess of
  **Knowledge**.
- Vishnu takes care of world from begining of life till death (Because
  he is palana karta). And his wife (Lakshami) helps in his duty (duty
  of paalan) by providing wealth to the humans. Because providing
  living standars is very important. All wealth or luxuries which includes
  cloths, homes, money is all provided by Goddess Lakshmi. She is
  Goddess of **wealth**.
- Shiva is Lord of distruction. Whatever has been made by Brahma, that
  need to be destroy one day. And that destruction is duty of Shiva.
  Shiva is Lord of death (Mahaakaal). And his wife Parvati helps in his
  duty of destruction by eleminating all bad demons by taking many
  different forms like Durga, kaali etc. She is Goddess of
  **power/strength.**

So by this explanation we can conclude that Tridev's duties is incomplete without Tridevis. Hence Tridevi also need to be there so that life process can be done flaslessly, without any compormises. Hence, Aadi Shakti need to take birth to make Shiva complete Since both Shiva and Parvati are no differ from each other and **Ardha Nareshwar** roop (form) of Shiva and Parvati is proof of that. So all Gods did pray to AAdi Shakti to take birth again. But Shiva didn't want her to take birth and also didn't want to marry with Aadi Shakti again.

This was just reason of needs towards world. But there is another reason also which is related to Shiva directly. Shiva loves his wife so much. We all know what happened with Shiva when Sati commit sucide, how much grief Shiva felt on death of Sati. Grief of saperation from Sati was unbearable for Shiva. So all Gods wanted to remove this grief of Shiva. So they all Prayed to Aadi Shakti to take birth again for Shiva.