# What was hanuman doing with sugreev on the mountain?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman

I mean sugreev was there because he was hiding from his brother bali, but what was hanuman doing with him? I mean how hanuman met sugreev

Comment: I didn't understand your last sentence. "Why  hanuman was in his country ruling his fathers kingdom?"

Comment: Sorry i want to write "why he wasn't in his fathers kingdom?"

Comment: Hanuman's adopted father Kesari wasn't the king of any empire.  He was just an ordinary Vanara.

Comment: But i have seen him in movies as king.!!!

Comment: Then the movies portrayed it wrongly.  The throne of Kishkindha went from Riksharaja to Vali to Sugriva to Vali to Sugriva to Angada. (Yes, I intentionally mentioned Sugriva and Vali twice.)

Comment: I think now it will appear as right question

Comment: @Keshav Where does Riksharaja come in Ramayana and who is he?

Comment: @Surya Riksharaja was the father (or technically mother) of Sugriva and Vali.  He's mentioned in various places in the Ramayana, but his full story is told in the Uttara Kanda: http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-41

Comment: Hanuman was being asked to protect Sugriva from Vali, that's why he was staying with Sugriva. Later he became minister of Sugriva also. Besides I am not fully sure who asked Hanuman to Protect Sugriva. May be Guru (Sun God) of Hanuman asked as guru dakshina.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan the link you mentioned itself says ‘Kesari reigned over Sumeru’ and I have also heard similar things. Also, it is to be noted that there was a hierarchy of chiefs and Kong’s and emperors in those days.

Answer (score 4):

**How hanuman met sugreev?**

Surya Deva appointed Hanuman as Sugriva's companion soon after Sugriva's birth:

> [image]
>   And having engaged Hanuman, Vayu's son in the service of Sugriva, Surya too went back to the sky.

Comment: You should post text rather than image in the answer. [OCR](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/616/277) can be useful. Also note that since the site language is English, you should provide English translation to Hindi explanation. [Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15425/277) is the list of useful resources for getting texts. You may discuss in chat if you need help with translation etc. Note that [image only](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1115/277) answers are considered of low quality and may be removed.

Comment: @Pandya i know but that was additional information...