# Best book with all Shlokas, Stotras?

Tags: book-recommendation

Best book/website(etc) with all Shlokas, Stotras and other songs..etc.. with their meaning in Sanskrit, Hindi, Kannada Or English..compilation of prayers of various Gods.

Comment: My priority is to get Book with prayer in Sanskrit with their meaning in Sanskrit.

Comment: Best website - Wikipedia!

Comment: Wikipedia is not as trustworthy as is seems. Use [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15424/what-are-some-online-sources-to-get-unabridged-hindu-scriptures-or-to-learn-hind/15425#15425) as a guide

Comment: "Best website...." This would be opinion based question. Btw, have a look at [What are some online sources to get unabridged Hindu Scriptures or to learn Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15425/277)

Comment: You can try **Strotra Ratnavali** by Gitapress

Comment: Stava Kusumanjali (by Ramakrishna Mutt) if I am remembering the name correctly. @HinduKid It has many stotras along with their word by word meanings. You just need to buy the book in the language of ur choice.

Answer (score 1):

A great website would be- www.sanskritdocuments.org. As for book, you cannot rest with just one. But you could see and take one or several from the catalouges of ramakrishna math, sringeri math, udupi  srikrishna math or iskcon etc . Do know that the maths may adhere to a set tradition and not have books having all stotras