# What is the direct relation between Chaitanya Mahaprabhu and Srila Prabhupada?

Tags: chaitanya, iskcon, prabhupada

For many days, I use to think that Chaitanya Mahaprabhu and Srila Prabhupada or A. C. Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupada is one and the same.

I use to quote many purports of Prabhupada in some of my answers on our site as they are widely available online and are agreeable to my scriptural knowledge. Actually, I don't know about him much previously. When I started knowing about him, I read many of his statements that *seem anti-scriptural to me*. Although I cannot say they are wrong without much research. It is just my opinions formed based on the current scriptural knowledge I have. Prabhupada founded ISKCON. I heard from many experts that ISKCON narrows down the Sanathan dharma. I also saw words like "demigods" when they are referring to gods other than Krishna, which generally no scriptures support. Recently I searched all my answers and replaced "demigod" with "god". So, I want to know about the authenticity of Prabhupada regarding lineage.

Is there any explicit and direct link between Chaitanya Mahaprabhu? If not, what is the complete (guru-sishya parampara) lineage till Prabhupada?

Comment: Chaitanya mahaprabhu taught the Goswami's to put further his message

Comment: Some people from iskcon said that Srila prabhupada belongs to the lineage of Chaitanya mahaprabhu

Comment: @Youwillnotknowme oh.. I want to know the complete lineage.

Comment: in the shreemadbhagavatgeeta of iskcon they give the complete lineage ni the introduction, which says he is from brahma sampradaya. However there are many debates on this

Comment: "I read many of his statements that seem anti-scriptural to me." Can you give an example?

Comment: @MassEnquirer **If one happens to be a kṣatriya he has the power to punish any man; therefore a kṣatriya should at once cut out the tongue of the vilifier and kill him**. https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/4/4/17/

Comment: @MassEnquirer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/42393/661

Comment: "I heard from many experts that ISKCON narrows down the Sanathan dharma." Yes, those who are triggered by Vaishnava philosophy will say just that, especially "Hindus" who are ignorant of scripture and its different philosophies (based on my personal experiences). It shouldn't be so hard for Sanatana Dharmis to respect each other's beliefs.

Comment: @hanugm Well I don't know much about that specifically, but sins, punishments, and atonement are all complicated. I wouldn't be surprised if there was a verse ordaining kshatriyas to cut a villifier's tongue. Blaspheming is a sin, and whether the punishment happens in this life or after death makes no difference considering our eternal time in samsara. Obviously, we should consult the scriptures (e.g. the dharma shastras) for specifics.

Comment: And @MassEnquirer you can check these: https://vaniquotes.org/wiki/Vivekananda_(Conversations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Srila Prabhupada comes in the direct line of succession of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu. His parampara can be found relatively easily if you search online:
[image]
https://www.iskconbangalore.org/guru-parampara/

Specifically, Chaitanya Mahaprabhu is the twenty-second person in the lineage coming from Krishna through Madhvacharya (fifth in the parampara and the beginning of the Brahma Sampradaya), and Srila Prabhupada is the thirty-second person in this lineage, tenth from Chaitanya Mahaprabhu.

> 22. **Lord Chaitanya**
> 23. Rupa Goswami, (Svarupa, Sanatana Goswami)
> 24. Raghunatha, Jiva Goswami
> 25. Krishnadasa
> 26. Narottama
> 27. Vishvanatha
> 28. Srila Jagannatha Dasa Babaji Maharaja,(Srila Baladeva Vidyabhushana)
> 29. Srila Bhaktivinoda Thakura
> 30. Srila Gaurakishora Dasa Babaji Maharaja
> 31. Srila Bhaktisiddhanta Sarasvati Thakura
> 32. **AC Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupada**