# What is the reason for which Advaita must exist? why can't Consciousness be many?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, consciousness

if we presume that matter is derived from consciousness(and this seems most likely),for what reason is this consciousness one instead of many?one could say that a world perceived as the same by all beings must come from a unified source,but this could be due to similar karmic traces?however one could say that we need to live in a unified reality already to bring about those initial karmic traces?

and even if we had initially similar karmic traces,the chances of producing a shared appearance from similar samskaras at the same time would be one in gazillions.and this would have to go on endlessly.it would be like fixing a rubix cube while blind for trillions of kalpas every minute without error.

interaction would be so improbable as to be functionally impossible,unless this shared vision were derived from a unified source,i.e nondual brahman?

Comment: The sentence "What reason is there Advaita?" does not appear to have a meaning. So I changed it by assuming what you meant to ask. See if my edit conveys your question correctly or not?

Comment: no you got it right

Answer (score 1):

because there is no arising or cessation of solid existants.nothing can give rise to anything substantially new,there is only change of condition from one form or state to another.for something to arise would mean that something could come from nothing.like say God existed,beings didn't,with what material did beings come into creation by?how could you give them subjective awareness?

exnihilo creation is quiet impossible.even though I am a absolute theistic monist,I concede that materialism makes much more sence than regular theism,the mind body problem and consciousness problem nonwithstanding.atleast materialism is a type of monism,where matter has always existed just in a different form before the bang.even within madhva's dvaita,where god and the souls share a similar substance,but matter does not it must be asked how matter and spirit can interact while being so mutually opposed.in Descartian philosophy this is called the interaction problem.

since there is no arising of solid existants,I would argue personally that consciousness must be self existant and doesn't come about thru the firing of matter.matter and mind duality has insurmountable problems like the interaction problem,and solutions like parallelism without saying that matter is in consciousness don't sound convincing since sequence of events of mind and matter must be cooordinated perfectely for everyone without fail and though technically possible it is functionally impossible.

and I would argue that because of this the material experience comes from consciousness and is in consciousness,and that because we share same reality there must be a unified substratum that unites all temporal minds.thus I am a monist.karmic traces or mental impressions creating appearances would have to be accumulated in a shared reality if you reject a unified mind,but this would only be possible to manifest based on shared realities in infinite regress,and even if this were possible,wich it isn't then our mental impressions would have to create a shared reality at the same time without fail infinitely since beginningless time and without fail forever.this is less probable than a blind man solving a rubics cube every 4 minutes for gazillions of aeons without fail.so there must be a unified mind.

I would like to hear your arguments against this.

even if we have a modified dvaita or bheda bheda where God controls the minds of beings by being substantially unified with them,one would have to ask how he can do this simultanouesly without end for infinite number of sentient beings to create a shared reality.one must also ask how he can influence the Minds of beings by merely being essentially united with them if his power cannot arise since his power is a seperate thing from him.I think the latter is a weak argument but the first holds ground.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! We [insist](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/803/official-policy-for-deleting-answers-that-dont-cite-sources) on citing some sources. Consider citing some authentic sources while answering questions. [Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15424/what-are-some-online-sources-to-get-unabridged-hindu-scriptures-or-to-learn-hind) you can find some useful resources for getting scriptures. Also visit [help] and [FAQ](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/478/277) to learn more about this site.