# How do I get mukti from a pran(vow)?

Tags: scripture, vedas

**How do I get mukti from a pran(vow)? I took a pran(vow) which I think I can't complete or may be I have already broken my vow**

Answer (score 1):

karmic manifestations work in a way that in our current form and loka it is quite difficult to relate & derive as to what has led to what .
now about the pran ,must have created a debit on your soul. but then again , your karma is limited only to the extent of putting genuine efforts while countering the Senses and Maya.result is in the hands of Krishna (as is explained in the Srimad Bhagvad Gita) so just leave it to him and do as he says.
secondly, Bhagwat Mahapuran clearly states that during :"Sankat" and "apatti" Kaal , rules can be more flexible, I may add that this is to the extent of being within orbit of Dharma and purity of heart.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. We insist on citing some authentic sources. You have mentioned Bhagavad Gita but missing the proper verse/chapter reference. Cite the verse(s) of Bhagavad Gita. [Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15425/277) you can find some useful resources to get texts.