# Does Shiva embody all the Gunas?

Tags: shiva

[This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/revisions/cc88ab84-5a83-4635-b492-38b4617452cf/view-source) is the source question asked by another user, with respect to which the above is asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes lord shiva embodies all the gunas.

Originally, lord sada shiva divided himself into Trinity which is lord Brahma (rajas Guna), lord vishnu (satva guna) and lord rudra (tamas guna).

As said by lord Krishna himself in Mahabharatam.:

> "O the lord of lord! **Myself** (Krishna/Vishnu), brahma, kapila, ananta (sheSha), all the valiant sons of brahma who conquered over the internal enemies - all **are created from you** (Shiva). Hence you are the lord of all. Hence you, the lord of all, are worthy of praise."

He balances everything by his trishool.:

These are some lines from Wikipedia which describes the significance of the trishool of mahadeva.

> The three points have various meanings and significance, and, common to the Hindu religion, have many stories behind them. They are commonly said to represent various trinities—creation, maintenance, and destruction; past, present, and future; body, mind and atman; dharma or dhamma (law and order), bliss/mutual enjoyment and emanation/created bodies; compassion, joy and love; spiritual, psychic and relative; happiness, comfort and boredom; pride, repute and egotism; clarity, knowledge and wisdom; heaven, mind and earth; soul, fire and earth; soul, passion and embodied-soul; logic, passion and faith; prayer, manifestation and sublime; insight, serenity and Bodhisattvahood or Arhatship (anti-conceit); practice, understanding and wisdom; death, ascension and resurrection; creation, order and destruction; the three gunas.

Thus lord shiv keep balance of these three gunas in the universe by holding the trishool...

Edit.:

According to Shiva maha Purana.:

> Vishnu, Rudra and I (Brahma) represent the Gunas.

> Siva is free from Gunas. He is the Supreme Brahman, the undecaying.

> Vishnu is of Sattva attribute, I (Brahma) am of Rajas attribute and Rudra is of Tamas attribute. This is only in the view of activities in this world. But in fact in name it is otherwise.

> Vishnu is Taamasik nature within

> Goddess of speech is Rajasic nature; Sati is of Saattvika nature and Lakshmi is of Taamasika nature; the great Goddess Sivaa is of three natures.

According to Sadhguru.:

> Sadhguru: Shiva’s trishul represents the three fundamental aspects of life. These are the three fundamental dimensions of life that are symbolized in many ways. They can also be called Ida, Pingala and Sushumna. These are the three basic nadis – the left, the right and the central – in the pranamaya kosha, or the energy body of the human system. Nadis are pathways or channels of prana in the system. There are 72,000 nadis that spring from the three fundamental ones.

> The Pingala and Ida represent the basic duality in the existence. It is this duality which we traditionally personify as Shiva and Shakti. You can simply call it masculine and feminine. When I say masculine and feminine, I am not talking in terms of sex – about being male or female – but in terms of certain qualities in nature. You could say the logical and the intuitive aspect of you.

> Bringing a balance between the Ida and Pingala will make you effective in the world; this will allow you to handle life aspects well. Most people live and die in Ida and Pingala. Sushumna, the central space, remains dormant. But Sushumna is the most significant aspect of human physiology. Life really begins only when energies enter into Sushumna. You attain to a new kind of balance, an inner balance where whatever happens outside, there is a certain space within you that never gets disturbed and cannot be touched by outside situations.

Lord Krishna said about Lord Siva in  the Anusashana Parva :
"namo 'stu te śāśvatasarvayone; brahmādhipaṃ tvām ṛṣayo vadanti

> **tapaś ca sattvaṃ ca rajas; tamaś ca tvām eva satyaṃ ca vadanti santaḥ"**(MBH 13:15:30)

> The blessed Krishna said, 'I saluted Mahadeva, saying,--Salutations to thee, O thou that art the eternal origin of all things. The Rishis say that thou art the Lord of the Vedas. The righteous say that thou art Penance, **thou art Sattwa, thou art Rajas, thou art Tamas, and thou art Truth**

I hope this do answer your question.

Comment: Wikipedia is [not considered reliable source here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1402/277). We expect some [authentic sources](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/277) to be cited, preferably [scriptures](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15425/277).

Comment: So I have cited from shiva Purana and from sadhguru's (who is a mordeen saint, have innumerable deciples and a large number of hindu sect follows him) direct quote though it's not in sanskrit but still it's a direct quote from his book. Now don't tell me that he is not a saint. Lol. .