# Which are the books that a Hindu should read?

Tags: vedanta, dharma, dharma-shastras

Which books are preferred the most for the below topics
1)to know what is dharma.
2)shastra(of do's and dont's)
3)Bhagavat Geeta bhashya.
4)Vyakarana.
5)Vedanta prakarana grantha.
Please suggest the books from basic to high level rankwise.

Comment: see this answer - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15425/5620

Comment: @SwiftPushkar thanks for guiding me, but I want to know about books not about sites. I feel book is better than site,althought I learn from sites but I need books.