# Where can I get AtharvaShiras Upanishad with Sanskrit & english translation?

Tags: scripture, upanishads, translation-request, translation

Where can I get AtharvaShiras Upanishad in english translation with Sanskrit Sloka in pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched up some meta posts on this website and found many wonderful
websites(many many thanks to our moderators Pandya and The Destroyer for
organising it so beautifully!)

I didn't find a single PDF for the same but found two separate links

1. [Atharvashira Upanishad (Sanskrit Shlokas)](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/atharvashira.html)

   (you could also get a pdf version for this on the same website)
2. [Atharvashira Upanishad English Translation by R.A.Shastri](https://shaivam.org/scripture/English-Translation/1293/atharvashira-upanishat-sastri)

(P.S. The translation begins after the Shanti Mantra(I am assuming you
understand basic Sanskrit shlokas so you can figure that out....))

I would also recommend you to go through the highly structured Hinduism
Meta Posts like [this one here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15424/what-are-some-online-sources-to-get-unabridged-hindu-scriptures-or-to-learn-hind)

Hope my answer helped you.If any problem arises pls do ask!

Comment: Thanks for the answer